# Can I arbitrarily end the witch hex disguise early?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch

> Disguise (Su): A witch can change her appearance for a number of hours equal to her class level, as if using disguise self. These hours do not need to be consecutive, but they must be spent in 1-hour increments.

Say I change my appearance, that knocks off one use for the day. Am I stuck this way for the entire hour? Or could I revert back to normal after a few minutes?

If the answer is yes, would I be able to use another use of the hex to change again within the same original hour time frame as long as a mark off another use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I voluntarily end a spell effect early?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75747/can-i-voluntarily-end-a-spell-effect-early)

Comment: @MarcDingena Definitely related, but it's not a duplicate. Supernatural abilities are sometimes different from spells they emulate (although that's not the case for this effect's duration).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes.

The ability says it works like [Disguise Self](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disguise-self/), which is *Dismissable*, thus allowing you to end the effect earlier.

> Duration 10 min./level (D)

The duration is different, but every other mechanic is unchanged, which includes the possibility of [dismissing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#Duration) the effect.

> (D) Dismissible
>
> If the duration line ends with “(D),” you can dismiss the spell at will. You must be within range of the spell’s effect and must speak words of dismissal, which are usually a modified form of the spell’s verbal component. If the spell has no verbal component, you can dismiss the effect with a gesture. Dismissing a spell is a standard action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

Now, if you do want to *change forms*, that counts as another use of the ability, and thus another *hour* must be spent.